# How to set a timer in the backend for 10 minutes?

Tags: django, redis, architecture, queue, backend

I have a ticket booking system for events. When someone wants to book a ticket, it should "reserve" it for n minutes for the person to purchase it. If he does not purchase it, then the ticket should be released after n minutes.

How should I go about doing this sort of system? I am thinking of storing the timestamp of each entry on redis or something, then checking every 10 seconds and if it has been n minutes without a confirmed booking, then I release the ticket?

I'm not sure if this approach will work and I don't know what to search on google on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. My backend is django if that is useful.

Comment: What about a "reserved_at" (datetime) and "reserved_by" field on the tickets, and a queryset that excludes ones recently reserved but allows purchase of ones reserved longer ago that that (nulling out "reserved_by" if  such a purchase happens)?  Obviously you have to re-check that a ticket is available when the person actually pays. First let him have his reserved ticket if it's still available, then re-check for other tickets and offer him those if they exist.

Comment: The alternative involves setting up a task scheduler such as Celery to expire reservations ten minutes later if a ticket remains unpurchased. This may be a sledgehammer to crack a nut. It's certainly non-trivial.